# Pushing git submodules correctly

Tags: git, push, git-submodules

I have the following repository layout:

```
Repo
|-- Folder1
|   |-- file1
|   |-- file2
|   ...
|-- Folder2
|   |-- file3
|   |-- file4
|   ...
|-- file5
|-- file6
...
```

Where 'Repo' is the main repository and 'Folder1' and 'Folder2' are two submodules.

Working with the root directory (file5, file6 in the example) is straight forward, but I have doubts about how to correctly push the items you modify inside the submodules.

Right now I'm editing the file inside each submodule, committing each change and pushing it localy:

```
[Repo]$ cd Folder1
[Folder1]$ vi file1
... do some changes ...
[Folder1]$ git add file1
[Folder1]$ git commit -m "Some changes"
[Folder1]$ git push
```

If I check git status on the submodule directly, it outputs that it's up to date:

```
[Folder1]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But if I check the status in the root folder, it tells me that the submodule that I've already pushed, has new commits.

```
[Folder1]$ cd ..
[Repo]$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Folder1 (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I suppose the above is due to git checking the current local repo commit ID vs the information in the git server I've pushed to. So, what I actually do now is commit all and push it up in the main repo. Is this the correct way to work with submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Repo]$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Folder1 (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The above is due to the parent repository `Repo` pointing to an older commit of the `Folder1` submodule.

To your other question, yes, this is the correct way to work with submodules.

1. Commit the submodule.
2. Push the submodule.
3. Commit in the parent repository.
4. Push the parent repository.

In this way you do not risk pushing a dangling submodule reference, i.e., a reference in the parent repository to a commit in the submodule that has not been pushed.

Notice that, in the parent repository, is not mandatory that you commit and push every submodule update. Other users can work in the `master` branch of the submodule, and do a standard `git fetch` / `git pull` to download new revisions.

I personally only commit a reference to a submodule when I'm going to release a new version of that submodule, to mark that release in the parent repository. My submodules are applications, and the parent repository is a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

> What I actually do now is commit all and push it up in the main repo.

If by this you mean "add each submodule to the root's index and commit/push the root," then you are correct.

The reason for this is that a submodule is considered a totally separate project from the main one.  Git allows you to specify an exact commit hash that the submodule is supposed to be at; this allows you to tightly control the version of the subproject that your main project uses.  When you update the subproject, you must manually update the referenced commit in the main project (and push that commit).

Note, *don't* commit and push references to submodules' commits that you don't intend to make public!  This will frustrate other developers by referencing work that they cannot access.  Also, as has been pointed out, you needn't commit-and-push the submodule to the main project, every time you make a change to the submodule, only when it reaches a new stable state.

Answer (score 0):

> In this way you do not risk pushing a dangling submodule reference, i.e., a reference in the parent repository to a commit in the submodule that has not been pushed.

To be extra sure, you can use git fsck with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021): the approach to "fsck" the incoming objects in "index-pack" is attractive for performance reasons (we have them already in core, inflated and ready to be inspected), but fundamentally cannot be applied fully when we receive more than one pack stream, as a tree object in one pack may refer to a blob object in another pack as "`.gitmodules`", when we want to inspect blobs that are used as "`.gitmodules`" file, for example.
Teach "index-pack" to emit objects that must be inspected later and check them in the calling "fetch-pack" process.

See [commit 5476e1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5476e1efded571e374cd97c7d69f17962ba1c44f), [commit b664e9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b664e9ffa153189dae9b88f32d1c5fedcf85056a), [commit 27e35ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27e35ba6c6b532ad6fc88b554d437b6892b4e915), [commit 726b25a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/726b25a91ba0e8f26f83c8d39ad16351b7bdb510) (22 Feb 2021) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6ee353d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ee353d42f389ec9454161b64ffbeb4167edebaa), 01 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5476e1efded571e374cd97c7d69f17962ba1c44f): print and use dangling .gitmodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> Teach index-pack to print dangling `.gitmodules` links after its "keep" or "pack" line instead of declaring an error, and teach fetch-pack to check such lines printed.
>
> This allows the tree side of the `.gitmodules` link to be in one packfile and the blob side to be in another without failing the fsck check, because it is now fetch-pack which checks such objects after all packfiles have been downloaded and indexed (and not index-pack on an individual packfile, as it is before this commit).

`git index-pack` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5476e1efded571e374cd97c7d69f17962ba1c44f/Documentation/git-index-pack.txt#L81-L86):

> For internal use only.
>
> Die if the pack contains broken objects. If the pack contains a tree
> pointing to a `.gitmodules` blob that does not exist, prints the hash of
> that blob (for the caller to check) after the hash that goes into the
> name of the pack/idx file (see "Notes").

And this is made more robust with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021):

See [commit 3745e26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3745e2693de3dd5420221782ed050cae6ebf6fec), [commit c96e184](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c96e184cae4294a4ebd18a1bdf8d6514445f32e4), [commit 462f5ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/462f5cae0f764569da4e6a7ab40ee1d3b85353ed), [commit c15087d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c15087d17bd3c146696bfe6abf86322d79bf61ca), [commit 53692df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53692df2b82f9d5ce15779da7d5227f1b027e193), [commit 394d5d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/394d5d31b0d3096aed4513bdacf48fb73003f1df), [commit 44e07da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44e07da8bb346c203246eae4f1a498844ee6d1ba), [commit 901f2f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/901f2f6742d55b2b73186a05261885dc824ed5cf), [commit b549502](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5495024ec655c56a98bdd3f9a5d4dfe578aa08f), [commit c72da1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c72da1a22bb3996ab8740b91ad2af6a54bd22777), [commit 30cf618](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30cf618eef09573a2f411e0b420e19f2f2e5a1c1), [commit 1b32b59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b32b59f9bd78b3475195a6e99c629a5ffefdea0), [commit e35d65a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e35d65a78ab7520b2705b27062758ab20a60e462), [commit 35af754](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35af754b0694eb26a253edf551efe400f30b3864), [commit 034a7b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/034a7b7bcc0ce5a7c3713173a1699ca8c9e722d5), [commit f1abc2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1abc2d0e146dc7f1549fd3ddb119e1b7f0ea645), [commit a1aad71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1aad71601a7a2052058d735ef86624b3cc774cf), [commit d385784](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d385784f89b3350db16380441bc8a18ebe54179a) (28 Mar 2021), and [commit fb79f5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb79f5bff7f47f41cf3697ecc28bfaa888016ce0) (17 Mar 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5644419](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5644419d04a6bb25c36c965acf0da0e700f1bd3f), 07 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3745e2693de3dd5420221782ed050cae6ebf6fec): use new fsck API to printing dangling submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Refactor the check added in [5476e1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5476e1efded571e374cd97c7d69f17962ba1c44f) ("`fetch-pack`: print and use dangling `.gitmodules`", 2021-02-22, Git v2.31.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ee353d42f389ec9454161b64ffbeb4167edebaa)) to make use of us now passing the `"msg_id"` to the user defined `"error_func"`.
> We can now compare against the `FSCK_MSG_GITMODULES_MISSING` instead of parsing the generated message.